# Why is logarithm in BMO

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

I read that $\log|x|$ is supposedly a typical example of a BMO function. How do I see that it is in BMO actually?

Comment: Never mind, its ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\log|x|$ is funny:
  Scaling $x$ adds a constant
    No matter for us.

Take a cube of size $1$.
  If it's placed near $0$,
    Then $\log|x|$ is not big.

On a far-away cube
  There's a gradient bound
    $\log|x|$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: This is not a background process answer.

Comment: Good enough for me.